# I am in MacOs and my Pygame window does not close

Tags: python, pygame

Window Class

```py
def __init__(self, window_dimension: tuple[int, int]):
        pygame.init()
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode(window_dimension)
        self.running = True
def check_quit(self, event_type: int): 
        if event_type == pygame.quit:
            self.running = False
```

Main

```py
WINDOW_DIMENSION = (600, 600)

win = Window(WINDOW_DIMENSION)

while win.running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        win.check_quit(event.type)
```

I don't get why this wouldn't work. I am in Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.quite()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) is a function that uninitializes all pygame modules and must be called after the application loop. The enumerated constant for the event type that occurs when the window is closed is `pygame.QUIT` (see [`event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module):

<s>`if event_type == pygame.quit:`</s>

```py
if event_type == pygame.QUIT:
```